# How to check multiple occurrences in the child records?

Tags: apex, list, collection, contains

I have a custom object called "Revence__c" with fields "profit1__c" and "profit2__c". Another custom object called "Product__c" is the parent of  "Revence__c"

If both profit1__c and profit2__c are same for more than one record, I need to display those records name. The below logic skips the first record information, when multiple occurences are there. For example, 'Prod1','Prod2','Prod3' has same profit1__c and profit2__c, it is currently displaying only 'Prod2' and 'Prod3' only

```java
    List<String> revList = new List<String>();
    for(Revence__c rev : prodDescList)
    {
        if(rev.profit1__c!= null && rev.profit2__c!= null )
        {
           if(revList.contains(rev.profit1__c+rev.profit2__c))
           {
               errorstring += rev.Name+' has some errors<br/>';
               errorstring +='Multiple occurences approval<br/>';
           }
           else
           {
                revList.add(pdl.profit1__c+pdl.profit2__c); 
                              
           }
        }          
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you had posted the correct code snippet? There is no comparison check for 'profit1__c' against 'profit2__c' in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does only display Prod2 and Prod3 because first contains will never have the Prod1 in it as it gets added in the else condition. What you need is having a map with rev.profit1__c+rev.profit2__c as keys and Reverence names as values as a list. So that way you can first populate the map and then check from there. Sample code for the logic:

```
        //create a map to hold all possible keys
        Map<String, List<String>> revMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();
        for(Revence__c rev : prodDescList) {
            if(rev.profit1__c != null && rev.profit2__c != null ) {
                //initialize list with either existing values or create new list
                List<String> values = revMap.get(rev.profit1__c+rev.profit2__c) != null ? revMap.get(rev.profit1__c+rev.profit2__c) : new List<String>(); 
                values.add(rev.profit1__c+rev.profit2__c);
                revMap.put(rev.profit1__c+rev.profit2__c, values);
            }
        } 
        
        for(String key : revMap.keySet()) {
            if(revmap.get(key).size() > 1) { //if key returns multiple values then add error message
                for(String dupValue : revmap.get(key)) {
                    errorstring += dupValue +' has some errors<br/>';
                    errorstring +='Multiple occurences approval<br/>';
                }
            }
        }
```

If `profit1__c` and `profit2__c` are String fields (which they look like they are) then instead of only checking not equal to `NULL`, I do recommend using `String.isNotBlank()` as it also checks for empty string.

Comment: if(revmap.get(key).values().size() > 1): It is showing 'Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void values() from the type List<String>'.

Comment: Yes, that was a problem on my part. I've updated the code. map.get already returns the value so values() was not necessary.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks a ton